# RubyMine console: Force Ruby / Rails to abort execution of miss typed statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I work quite a bit from within the rails console inside RubyMine and get really frustrated by the following situation:

```
>> User.find_by_name("Joe).id   
# Oh no, I forgot the closing double quote marks
# I'll try and cause an exception
>> "
>> ""
>> end
>> exit
# Well this is frustrating...
>> Foo
>> Bar
# rage quit
```

The console continually waits and all i want to do is break my expression. I have to end up closing the console (or RubyMine entirely) and restarting it.

Is there any better way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out with RubyMine **6.0**.

Use `CTRL` `+` **`SHIFT`** `+` `C`

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, pressing `Ctrl+d` and then typing a parenthesis `)` should do:

```
1.9.3p194 :004 > Team.find_by_name("equipo1).id
1.9.3p194 :005"> cannot get out of here"
1.9.3p194 :006?>   hold on...
1.9.3p194 :007 >     ^D
1.9.3p194 :007?>   )
SyntaxError: (irb):6: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
hold on...
    ^
(irb):7: syntax error, unexpected ')'
    from /Users/dgarcia/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/dgarcia/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/dgarcia/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3p194 :008 > puts "hooray!!"
hooray!!
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :009 >
```

Comment: I am referring to being inside the RubyMine console - `CTRL` + * don't seem to be captured hence this is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Just press ctrl c and it will get out of this mode.

```
irb(main):265:0* "hello
irb(main):266:0"
irb(main):267:0"
irb(main):268:0"
irb(main):269:0" ^C
irb(main):269:0>
```